# How to compile and run correctly a windows forms application

Tags: c++, compilation

I added the `C++ Windows Forms Application` project to Visual Studio 2012, but I can't compile programs made with it correctly. When I press the "Local Compiler Windows" button, it doesn't compile it as it is. All the buttons, text boxes and etc. are not seen, just a white window. How can I compile it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

**1.Build your program first**

```
File Menu---Build---Build ProjectName
```

**2. Run it**(shortcut F5 or the triangle shaped icon).

```
 File Menu ---Debug--Start Debugging
```

**Single step for building and running it:**

Running the project directly, will  automatically prompt for a build(if it hasn't been built yet) and then run the program.